# Resolve domain to subdomain

Tags: apache-http-server, domain, cname

Want to resolve full domain name to a subdomain on a second domain:

For instance, if I have this subdomain:

```
subdomain.firstdomain.com
```

Second domain:

```
seconddomain.com
```

I want seconddomain.com resolve on the first subdomain so the user always will be looking, for instance: **seconddomain.com/whatever.html** instead of **subdomain.firstdomain.com/whatever.html**

**Both domains are on the same server, same IP and we have full control.**

I hope I have been clear in my explanation.

Maybe configuring CNAME or adding a .htaccess file?

Comment: edit your question to include the for each of  **`firstdomain.com`** and **`seconddomain.com`**: **[1]** the webhosting environments; **[2]** where the DNS is hosted; **[3]** whether you control the domains

Comment: "resolve" is not the right word, resolving implies resolving domain name to IP address, which is not what you want - I think the keyword you need to look for is *redirect*, which can be achieved using .htaccess I believe (though, I haven't used crapache for many years now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want however, regardless the approach, you will need:

1. DNS Record(s) that point to your Apache server.
2. Apache rewriting (redirecting, remapping, etc.) server-side to change the hostname displayed from **`subdomain.firstdomain.com`** to **`seconddomain.com`**

##### 1.   DNS Records

You haven't provided any info but wherever your DNS for **`firstdomain.com`** is hosted, you will need to create an **A Record** or a **CNAME Record** for **`subdomain.firstdomain.com`** as well as another one for the **`www`** version if you want that included.

- if using **A Records**, you'd enter your Apache server's public IP address
- if using **CNAME Records**, you'd enter a hostname such as **`seconddomain.com`** that already resolves to your Apache server's public IP address

Example: DNS Records

| Type | Domain | IP/Hostname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | `subdomain.firstdomain.com` | `###.###.###.###` |
| **CNAME** | `www.subdomain.firstdomain.com` | `subdomain.firstdomain.com` |

##### 2.   Apache: Rewriting

There are different approaches, but given that your goal is to use **`seconddomain.com`** instead of the other hostnames **`subdomain.firstdomain.com [www.subdomain.firstdomain.com]`** to reach the same site, [Canonical Hostnames](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#page-header:%7E:text=you%27re%20working%20in.-,Canonical%20Hostnames,-Description%3A) are intended for this use, so may be a good approach.

The following rule doesn't involve `mod_rewrite`, but uses the [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive placed in a virtual host for the non-canonical hostname(s):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.firstdomain.com
  ServerAlias www.subdomain.firstdomain.com

  Redirect "/" "http://seconddomain.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName seconddomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache Rewrite: [Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

Comment: Thanks... DNS records woks best for me.

Comment: You need both.  DNS will get the request for `http://subdomain.firstdomain.com/*` to your server but the address **will not change** to `http://seconddomain.com/*` without also implementing the Apache rewrite.